# Evaluate the integral $ \ \int \int_R (x^2+y^2) (x^2-y^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} dA \ $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral $$\iint_R (x^2+y^2) (x^2-y^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} dA,$$
where $ \ R \ $ is the region bounded by the graphs $ x=0, x=1, \ y=0, \ y=1 \ $ by means of changing variables $ u=2xy, \ v=x^2-y^2$.

**Answer:**

$$ u^2+v^2=(x^2+y^2)^2 \ \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=\sqrt{u^2+v^2},$$

Also, $ 0 \leq u \leq 2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ -1 \leq v \leq 1$.

Now,

$$\frac{\partial{(u,v)}}{\partial(x,y)}=-4(x^2+y^2)=-4 \sqrt{u^2+v^2},$$

thus, \begin{align*}
\iint_R (x^2+y^2) (x^2-y^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} dA &= \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} v^{\frac{1}{3}} \left|\frac{\partial{(u,v)}}{\partial(x,y)} \right|^{-1} dudv \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} v^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{u^2+v^2}} dudv \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} v^{\frac{1}{3}}dudv =0.
\end{align*}

**Please check my work.**

Comment: I haven't checked your work but writing teh double integral as a repeated integral and chnaging the order of integratiom makes it obvious that the answer is 0 (since $(y^{2} - x^{2})^{1/3} =-(x^{2}-y^{2})^{1/3}$

Comment: I could have just said the transformation $(x,y) \to (y,x)$ gives the value of the integral as 0.

Comment: The limits for $u,\,v$ in  transformed integral are important and it is not clear how they are obtained.